# Invalid composite PK specification: the names of the PK fields or properties in the PK class and those of the entity class must correspond

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-8, eclipselink, jpa-2.2

I have the following simple design:

[image]

A player stat is a per-player stat that holds state for the whole game for a player, e.g. the jersey number.

It references a team member, which is identified by a player in a specific roster (basically, a player can be part of multiple rosters, e.g. players playing for multiple teams in a season).

A player stat is tied to the score of a game, either the home or the away score. It's basically a join table with additional properties/columns. You get the idea.

So both tables being referenced by the `PlayerStats` table have a composite PK. I mapped the `PlayerStat` entity using **derived identifiers**, see below.

Score entity + ID class (nothing special):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Scores")
@IdClass(ScoreId.class)
public class Score implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "game_id")
    private Integer gameId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "is_home")
    private Boolean home;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "final_score")
    private Integer finalScore;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "score")
    private List<PlayerStat> playerStats;

    ...
}

public class ScoreId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer gameId;

    private Boolean home;

    ...
}
```

Team member entity + ID class (nothing special):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TeamMembers")
@IdClass(TeamMemberId.class)
public class TeamMember implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private Integer playerId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "roster_id")
    private Integer rosterId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamMember")
    private List<PlayerStat> playerStats;

    ...    
}

public class TeamMemberId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer playerId;

    private Integer rosterId;
    
    ...
}
```

Player stat entity + ID class (**derived identifiers**):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PlayerStats")
@IdClass(PlayerStatId.class)
public class PlayerStat implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "jersey_nbr")
    private Integer jerseyNbr;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "game_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "is_home", referencedColumnName = "is_home")
    private Score score;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "player_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "roster_id", referencedColumnName = "roster_id")
    private TeamMember teamMember;
    
    ...
}

public class PlayerStatId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ScoreId score;

    private TeamMemberId teamMember;

    public PlayerStatId()
    {
    }

    public ScoreId getScoreId()
    {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScoreId(ScoreId scoreId)
    {
        this.score = scoreId;
    }

    public TeamMemberId getTeamMemberId()
    {
        return teamMember;
    }

    public void setTeamMemberId(TeamMemberId teamMemberId)
    {
        this.teamMember = teamMemberId;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Exception:

```
11:44:27,315 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."bbstatstest-1.0.war#BBStatsPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."bbstatstest-1.0.war#BBStatsPU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7150] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStatId] and those of the entity bean class [class net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStat] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:658)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7150] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStatId] and those of the entity bean class [class net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStat] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2085)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:316)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:365)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$1300(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:190)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [BBStatsPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7150] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStatId] and those of the entity bean class [class net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStat] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:233)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7150] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStatId] and those of the entity bean class [class net.bbstats.entity.PlayerStat] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidCompositePKSpecification(ValidationException.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.validatePrimaryKey(EntityAccessor.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2006)
    ... 14 more
```

**QUESTION**:

What's wrong with the mappings?

The `PlayerStat` entity has two relationships `score` and `teamMember` and the respective `@IdClass` called `PlayerStatId` has two **nested composite PK** class references called `score` and `teamMember` as required and their types are the respective PK classes `ScoreId` and `TeamMemberId`.

I'm using the latest EclipseLink 2.7.7 in a WildFly 20 env.

Could this be a bug of some kind?

I looked at several sources describing derived identifiers, but I don't see anything inherently wrong with the mappings.

Comment: If I am not mistaken [repeatable annotation](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-2-2-repeatable-annotations/) was added in jpa 2.2.

Comment: True. It's a feature of Java 8. JPA 2.2 is part of Java EE 8. I changed the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do composite ids when the parts of the composite id are also composite ids. The types of the attributes also need to match: `Integer gameId` matches, but `ScoreId score` is not the same as `Score score`.

You might be able to do it by unnesting the id classes and fiddling about with `JoinColumn` definitions, or you'll have to bite the bullet and give your entities artificial primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

The mappings are absolutely correct and working. I had another test app still deployed on the server with the same package/class names, so the errors came from the other app. Sorry for the confusion. Question could be deleted entirely.